# Google Chrome not running when Chromedriver tries to access it - EC2 instance

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I've looked at so many suggested solutions to this issue, and yet none apply or have worked for me. I'm trying to test updating chromedriver and google-chrome on our staging server and having no luck.

We were using an older version of `selenium-webdriver`, so I updated as far as we could go (we are on Ruby 2.3.6), so our versions stand at:

```
selenium-webdriver: 3.142.7
capybara: 2.7.1
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-1093-aws
Architecture: x86-64

$ which chromedriver
/usr/bin/chromedriver
$ which google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome
$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604daa9cc128ccf5a5d3e993513758913-refs/branch-heads/5414@{#1172})
$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 109.0.5414.74
```

I've been running it somewhat like this. I added the `Service` instance after moving to selenium webdriver `3.142.7`

```
def set_defaults
  options = set_options
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chromeOptions: options)
  service = Selenium::WebDriver::Service.chrome(path: '/usr/bin/chromedriver')
  selenium_options = { browser: :chrome, desired_capabilities: capabilities, service: service }
  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, selenium_options)
  end
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
end

def set_options
  user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument("--user-agent='#{user_agent}'")
  options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1280,1024')
  options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') # I added this after reading other answers on SO, but it didn't make a difference
  options
end
```

The vast majority of this was set up previously and working until we needed to update our chromedriver/google-chrome versions, which is what I'm testing.

Here is the error I'm seeing when trying to run the above code:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
    from #0 0x55b693029303 <unknown>
    from #1 0x55b692dfdd37 <unknown>
    from #2 0x55b692e26157 <unknown>
    from #3 0x55b692e22330 <unknown>
    from #4 0x55b692e634a6 <unknown>
    from #5 0x55b692e5a753 <unknown>
    from #6 0x55b692e2da14 <unknown>
    from #7 0x55b692e2eb7e <unknown>
    from #8 0x55b69307832e <unknown>
    from #9 0x55b69307bc0e <unknown>
    from #10 0x55b69305e610 <unknown>
    from #11 0x55b69307cc23 <unknown>
    from #12 0x55b693050545 <unknown>
    from #13 0x55b69309d6a8 <unknown>
    from #14 0x55b69309d836 <unknown>
    from #15 0x55b6930b8d13 <unknown>
... 7 levels...
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:167:in `execute'
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:102:in `create_session'
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:56:in `handshake'
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:43:in `initialize'
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:46:in `new'
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:46:in `for'
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for'
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:14:in `browser'
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:46:in `visit'
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:233:in `visit'
    from (irb):21
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /var/www/apps/einstein_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:21:in `require'
    from script/rails:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The error suggests that Chrome did not create the file that Chromedriver needs to read in order to get the SessionID.  Check to be sure that Chrome can write files/create directories.  You may also want to run Chrome at least once manually so that it can create initial directories/configs.  You should also try running without any options set.  Sending a bad option can cause crashes on startup.  I haven't used Selenium in Ruby, but the latest version of Selenium will be 4.x... I think Ruby bindings would be here: https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver/versions/4.7.0

Comment: I would also avoid "no-sandbox" option unless it's absolutely necessary.  (for security...)

Comment: you can use Selenium 4.1 if you are limited to Ruby 2.6. Highly recommend not using `--headless` since it is not a production browser; either use xvfb or `--headless=chrome`.

Comment: @pcalkins - thanks! Yeah, When I run `google-chrome` at the command line in the server, I get an error message about not finding X or $DISPLAY, but I have assumed that that is because it needs Chromedriver to be running google-chrome, not just being able to run google-chrome on its own. Also, I've tried without any options and still get the same error, unfortunately. Appreciate the help and response. - ETA: Yeah, the `--no-sandbox` option was put there before my time and I'm hesitant to remove, but I hear you.

Comment: @titusfortner I misspoke - we're on Ruby 2.3.6. I'll edit my post.

Comment: without a display doesn't seem like this option would work: options.add_argument('--window-size=1280,1024')  I would add back in only the disable-gpu and headless flags.  You might also consider something like HTMLUnit.  (or check if there's a "virtual display"... I think that's what titusfortner is getting at with xvfb.)

Comment: Ruby 2.3 went EOL in 2019 - I would suggest you have bigger security issues to worry about than the —no-sandbox option. Put your efforts into upgrading everything necessary to move to a modern Ruby

Comment: @ThomasWalpole - yeah, there's no question there. Still, though, with everything I've found it seems like what I have should work but that I'm missing some simple thing that is making the setup not run. If my versions are correct, matching, and the gem versions supposedly work off of each other, why isn't it launching? What I don't want is to do a Ruby upgrade and then find myself with the same problem - I want to understand what the problem actually is. I've got some tips here that I'll work from for now, then look at other options.

Comment: @Magpie Also, Capybara 2.7.1 was released in May of 2016 ...  I would be VERY surprised if it will run with an up to date version of chrome/chromedriver.  You really need to start updating things other than just chrome/chromedriver if you want anything to work

Comment: @ThomasWalpole - Yeah, that looks like where we're headed. Way too much tech debt, for sure. I appreciate the feedback on this.

Comment: @pcalkins - would you mind clarifying something for me? I'm assuming I just am understanding the function of ChromeDriver incorrectly, but why would a display like `Xvfb` be needed at this point now if it was working without it before? Just version updates? I had assumed ChromeDriver was what was handling that display previously, but that seems wrong now if something like `Xvfb` or a display of some sort is required.

Comment: I was thinking the browser, not the driver was crashing on startup because there is no display.  HOWEVER, according to this, no display or virtual display is needed: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/headless-chrome/#faq  I don't know how up to date that info is though...  it also states that the disable-gpu flag is only needed in Windows.

Comment: I would check this link: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/help/chrome-doesn-t-start

Comment: @pcalkins - Right. When I try to start google chrome (typing `google-chrome` at the command line in the ec2 instance), I get `Missing X server or $DISPLAY` error. Maybe because at that point, with just the command line prompt, I'm not using a headless declaration.  I'm going to try the Xvfb addition today, and then move to upgrading after that.

Comment: you should try with headless flag: google-chrome --headless

Comment: @pcalkins - thanks, I believe I had tried that at some point and I got the same error. Finally, installing Xvfb is what did the trick.